# How to replace text with null in powerquery?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I would like to replace "ValueToReplace" with `null` in powerquery. This does not work (returns error):

```
Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous Step","ValueToReplace", null ,Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Col1"})
```

This works but it returns "" instead of null:

```
Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous Step","ValueToReplace","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Col1"})
```

Comment: I have noticed that I cannot get null on TEXT type column. First I have to change it to Type ANY. Nevertheless it is strange. Because afterwards I can change column containing null to type TEXT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's because `null` isn't a text value, so you need to use `ReplaceValue` instead of `ReplaceText`.

```
Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous Step","ValueToReplace",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Col1"})
```